# String REG REPLACE in CMAKE

Tags: cmake

1. I am searching header files  in a directory
2. Replacing LONG string in all header files to SVN_LONG.
3. I don't wan't to replace *LONG,LONG*,*LONG* to SVN_LONG.
4. When I run below code it's replacing SLONG to SSVN_LONG, LONG to SVN_LONG etc..

So how to avoid SLONG, LONGINT not to replace, only LONG string have to replace SVN_LONG?

```
file ( GLOB headerfiles "../common/include/tar/*.h")
if ("${grep_word}" STREQUAL "")
    SET (searchreg "LONG")
    foreach( eachheaderfile ${headerfiles} )
        MESSAGE(STATUS " INFILES= ${eachheaderfile}\n")
        FILE(READ ${eachheaderfile} file_content)
        #MESSAGE(STATUS " FILES_content= ${file_content}")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "${searchreg}" "SVN_LONG" modified_file_content "${file_content}" )
        FILE(WRITE ${eachheaderfile} ${modified_file_content})
        FILE(READ ${eachheaderfile} file_content1)
        MESSAGE(STATUS " FILES_content= ${file_content1}")
    endforeach(eachheaderfile)

    #MESSAGE(STATUS " outFILES= ${headerfiles}\n") 
endif()
```

Answer (score 1):

As usual with regular expressions, you need to match symbols before replaced string and restore them in replacement string. Command `string(REGEX REPLACE)` supports *backslashed references* for that purpose:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "([^a-zA-Z])LONG|^LONG" "\\1SVN_LONG"
    modified_file_content ${file_content})
```

Given command matches single symbol, which should be different from the letter, before word `LONG` and restore this symbol via backslash reference `\1`  (symbol "\" need to be doubled in the cmake command, because it is parsed by CMake itself before going to the command).

Alternation started with `^` is needed for match `LONG` at the beginning of the string.